# Can a PersistedModel relation name be the same as the property name?

Tags: loopbackjs

In the [Loopback documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Embedded-models-and-relations.html#embedsone) relations always have different names than the property they are stored in. For example:

```
{
  "name": "Customer",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "address": {
      "type": "embedsOne",
      "model": "Address",
      "property": "billingAddress",
      "options": {
        "validate": true,
        "forceId": false
      }
   }
   ...
}
```

Note in this case the `address` relation has a property of `billingAddress`. Things seem to break when we use a property of `address` as instead.

Sometimes its hard to come up with an arbitrary adjective to prepend to the property. For example, say the relation was to a model already called `BillingAddress` instead of `Address`. It would be natural to want to name both the relation and the property `billingAddress`.

For example:

```
{
  "name": "Customer",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "billingAddress": {
      "type": "embedsOne",
      "model": "BillingAddress",
      "property": "billingAddress",
      "options": {
        "validate": true,
        "forceId": false
      }
   }
   ...
}
```

How do you handle this situation in Loopback?

Comment: Not sure what kind of issues are you facing, but what I do is just name the relation the same as the related model, except in camelCase instead of MixedCase. e.g. `CustomerAccount hasMany Project`, the relation is called `project`. And viceversa, in `Project belongsTo CustomerAccount`, the relation is called `customerAccount`. This might not be what you are looking for but it works for me so just maybe it's an option.

Comment: If I recall correctly we were previously running into issues with the embedded model not being emitted when you serialized the parent model. I think this is because the data `model.embedded` was overriding the function `model.embedded()`

Comment: In my experience, no. The related model is treated as a new property, so if you use the same name, one of them would be lost.

Answer (score 1):

With the current state of loopback, I believe it's a bad idea. I tried it a few times on different types of relationships having the same reasons you came up with, in most cases it breaks something if it works. Looking at the documentation and loopback I can tell relationships were designed in a way that relation name and the property must be different, even if it works, it might break in the future.

For these things I would add a postfix to the relation name, for example `billingAddressDetails` or `billingAddressRelation`.

In the mean time you could also open an issue in github, but I think things will stay the same way in the future.